# How to iterate through arraylists if they represents Sums?

Tags: java, list

If I would know the number of the summations I could write the same number of for statements. However I don't know exactly.

[image]

The picture is just an example: I can solve this by iterating through 2 for statements. But my problem is I have an ArrayList which contains the variables (in this case: i, j).

Here is my exact problem:
B, J and M are fixed values and the we don't know the exact value of f and r what we know is only a range and they are needed to be sum. Unfortunately, I don't know in advance which value is fixed.

[image]

```
public class MyClass {

ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

Comment: Could you post some code you have already tried, and the actual contents of the `ArrayList`s?

Comment: From what I understand, you can iterate through the arraylist ```for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)``` and you get the element by ```list.get(i)```. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: We're gonna need some more parameters to work with here.  You say the ArrayList contains the variables `i` and `j`.  What about the upper bounds?  Does the first summation always go to 10?  And the second summation is inconsistent in your picture.  What determines that?  Is the actual formula always the same?

Comment: If you're just asking on a more basic level "How do I loop through an ArrayList?", please see [ArrayList#forEach()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)).

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Is it a programming question or a mathematical one ?